# How to add a email share button that does that has the subject line and body filled in but not the send address

Tags: html, wordpress, email, social-media

I am working on a Wordpress website that has social share buttons after creating a post. For the email email share button when a user clicks on the email button it acts as a mail to link and automatically opens a users email client and fills in the send address to the parent site and keeps everything blank.

I want to know how to configure that email button so that when a user clicks the email share button the subject line and body should be filled with the title/link/summary of the news article or event article that they want to share, and the send to line is blank.

Any suggestion on plugins?

Comment: Not that I condone this, but I believe you could achieve this by using HTML (no plug-ins required). Something like this might work: <a href="mailto:example@email.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Email%20Body%20Text">Share this</a> (Note: %20 translates to a space.) You might be able to leave the 'example@email.com' out, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: What is the plugin you are currently using for social share buttons?

Comment: I was using Easy Social Share Buttons for WordPress. Which automatically was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out the issue:
One way is using a WP plugin which automatically keeps the To blank, the subject is the post title, and the body is the link.

The other way I found it worked is to use a php function in the mail to link in order to pull the the content

```
<a href="https://www.exampleSocialMediaSite/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>%2F&title=<?php echo $description; ?>&source=" target="_blank">
```

or `<a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">LINK TEXT</a>`